# Display popup in Suagrcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

When creating a contact , I check by Javascript if that contact already exists.
If it does I am displaying text that  "Contact Alreay Exists".
I have displayed an information icon besides the message.

I want to achieve the following :

On hover of that icon it should display the already available contact id and when clicked opens that particular contact in Detail view.

[image]

Comment: How are you generating the "i" icon currently?

Comment: Right now on tab of last name calling ajax function that calls a php file that check for if name already exists and if it does displaying the text and the icon image.thats it.

Comment: If you know that a contact with the same name exists then I assume you know that contacts's ID.  You can then just generate a link to the contact's detail view using the ID.  It seems you've already done all the hard work!

Comment: Yes I know it that way.But I want to display the i icon popup  like on list view.

Comment: Give us the code you're using to display the "This Name Already Exists (i icon)" currently, and we'll see if we can adjust it to become a link instead of a static image.